# Encoding problems with RSS using Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, encoding, character-encoding, rss

I have a trouble reading RSS feeds that uses 'special' characters, for example, [this](http://www.barakaldo.org/portal/html/rss/noticias/search.jsp?languageId=es_ES) feed is Spanish and contains characters like á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ç, ñ... when I open it in a browser (Chrome, in my case) that characters are shown correctly.

Now, I'm trying to read this feed using the `request` library on Node.js. This is my code:

```
const rq = require('request');

module.exports.request = (url, method, json, body, headers) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  rq({
    url,
    method,
    json,
    body,
    headers
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(body);
    }
  })
);

let feed = rq(URL_HERE, 'GET', false, undefined, HEADERS_HERE)
```

In this code, I've tried usin HTTP headers like `Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8` to force the page to render in UTF-8 (this encoding supports that characters) but nothing, when the request is recieved special characters are shown with a `?` symbol.

The printing in the console isn't the problem either, because that feed data is directly saved into Firebase Firestore database and I have that `?` in the database too.

I've tried libraries and methods like `utf8_encode`, `utf8_decode`, `iconv` and the same result, special characters with `?` symbol.

What I'm thinking is, the RSS XML enconding header shows `ISO-8859-1` and I'm trying to force the web to be parsed using UTF-8 and is not working correctly, but **why is shown correctly in the browser**?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Some results to clarify comments, the expected result should be:

```
Las banderas del Ayuntamiento ondearán mañana a media asta.
```

**1: A simple request without decoding**

Code:

```
const request = require('request');

const myRequest = (url, method, json, body, headers) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  request({
    url,
    method,
    json,
    body,
    headers
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(body);
    }
  })
);

myRequest('http://www.barakaldo.org/portal/html/rss/noticias/search.jsp?languageId=es_ES', 'GET')
  .then((feed) => console.log(feed))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Result:

```
Las banderas del Ayuntamiento ondear�n ma�ana a media asta.
```

**2: Same request but decoding from `latin1` and `iso-8859-1` using `iconv-lite`**

Code:

```
const request = require('request');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

const myRequest = (url, method, json, body, headers) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  request({
    url,
    method,
    json,
    body,
    headers
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(body);
    }
  })
);

myRequest('http://www.barakaldo.org/portal/html/rss/noticias/search.jsp?languageId=es_ES', 'GET')
  .then((feed) => {
    let decodedFeed = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(feed), 'latin1');
    console.log(decodedFeed);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Result:

```
Las banderas del Ayuntamiento ondearï¿½n maï¿½ana a media asta.
```

Comment: "why is shown correctly in the browser" — Presumably, because the browser is respecting the encoding header.

Comment: Your code is missing the bit where you output the data.

Comment: @Quentin I've added more code and the output of the data, thanks for your help!

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The feed is encoded in ISO-8859-1, so that's the encoding you need to decode it.

Putting a Content-Type header field on the request won't have an effect; it would describe the type of the *request* body (which is empty for GET).

Comment: I've tried decoding `ISO-8859-1` and `latin1` using `iconv-lite` and the results are different but unreadable, I've edited the post to show you the code and the output.